# Maintain selected row position after sorting DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I keep my selected row in its existing position after I sort my DataGridView?

I have code that runs on the sorted event of my DatGridView. It remembers the selected row and highlights it in the grid, the issue is that it moves the position of the row.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customerCode))
{
    int itemFound = DGVBindingSource.Find("Code", customerCode); // Code is name of column to search.
    DGV.Position = itemFound;                    
}
```

I have tried adding the line of code below but it just moves the row to the top of the grid. I would like it to remain in the original position?

```
DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DGV.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Any help appreciated?

Comment: dont use the index. just remember the row and then highlight it

Comment: When I search it after the sort, set the DGV position, it still changes position in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [DevExpress GridView class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.members) would be helpful solution to your task.